# Intellij Idea - how to maintain multiple versions of the package in one project?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have case as follows and don't know if there is any conveninet solution:
I wrote some set of sources and put them in into a package.
Next, I refactored it deeply for performance reasons.
Now, I have new version which contains at least one bug, that I have to find.
I would like to have both version of my package in one project and easily switch between them
when I compile and run test application.
Of course I can compile both of them and choose in runtime because of names conflicts.
Is it any smart way to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like version control would help you here.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a version control system (which is supported through intellij IDEA).

Try git, they have good support in IDEA.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-git-integration.html
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html

Here is a good link for git / vcs tutorials.

http://sixrevisions.com/resources/git-tutorials-beginners/

Comment: Currently I use bzr from outside IJ. I wonder if VCS used from IJ can serve me without need to copy/paste branches addresses or revision numbers each time. I would like to have some one-click-switch

Comment: With IntelliJ you have a dropdown in lower right corner, just pick whichever branch you want to use and IntelliJ will switch to that branch right away.